# Wordpress custom table update not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to update wp_table (custom table) via frontend.
i want update records in self submitted page $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
after update sucesfully i want redirect user to home page. but not working

```
$domain = $_POST['domain'];
$appointment = $_POST['appointment'];
$rid = $_POST['rid'];
global $wpdb;
if (!isset($_POST['save'])) {
    if (mysql_query("UPDATE wp_domain SET domain='$domain', appointmenttime_setting='$appointment' WHERE re_id=$rid"))
    {
    //echo "UPDATE wp_domain SET domain='$domain', cron_setting='$twitime' WHERE re_id=$rid";
    header( 'Location:http://localhost/thepost/?page_id=17' ) ;
    }
}
```

My html code is here

```
<form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
    <table width="300" border="1">
  <tr style="width:450px;">
    <td>Domain</td>
    <td>
    <?php
    $act = $Rrow->active_not;
    if($act=="NO")
    { ?>
        <input name="domain" value="<?php echo $Rrow->domain; ?>" type="text">
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        echo $Rrow->domain;
    }
    ?>

    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Appointment Time</td>
    <td><select name="appointment">
      <option value="5 Minute">5 Minute</option>
      <option value="10 Minute">10 Minute</option>
      <option value="15 Minute">15  Minute</option>
      <option value="30 Minute">30 Minute</option>
      <option value="45 Minute">45 Minute</option>
      <option value="1 Hour">1 Hour</option>
     </select>
     <input type="hidden" name="rid" value="<?php echo $Rrow->re_id; ?>" />
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a class="btn">SAVE</a></td>
    <td><input name="save" id="save" type="submit" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>    
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel your issue is with if `(!isset($_POST['save']))` and `mysql_query` instead of `wp_query`, try like this

```
if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
    if (wp_query("UPDATE wp_domain SET domain='$domain', appointmenttime_setting='$appointment' WHERE re_id=$rid")){
       header( 'Location:http://localhost/thepost/?page_id=17' ) ;
       exit;
    }
}
```